# How to specify a custom kernel for OpenCV medianBlur() (horizontal median filter)

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

The OpenCV `medianBlur` function takes a `ksize` parameter, which lets you specify the size of the kernel — but as far as I can tell, this is limited to square kernels. It makes a square kernel using `ksize` for both the width and height.

Is it possible to specify custom kernel dimensions? My use case is to generate a horizontal median filter.

Comment: You could consider trying the **scikit-image** version... https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.filters.html#skimage.filters.median

Comment: Or **wand** has `filter.statistic('median', width, height...)` https://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.5/wand/image.html#wand.image.BaseImage.statistic

Comment: Or **SciPy** https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.median_filter.html

Comment: Or you can resize your image in one direction.

Comment: Or **DIPlib**’s [`dip.MedianFilter()`](http://diplib.org/diplib-docs/group__nonlinear.html#gabdb6653221f497eab30295089b229b35).

Comment: Not implemented as far as I know, you can check the source code [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/median_blur.simd.hpp). Might be worth a shot opening a feature request or extending the function yourself, though it might need a while to get merged